# How can I modify the trainable tf.Variables in a TensorFlow-Hub Module to use a custom kernel initializer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I would like to train an InceptionV3 Neural Network from scratch. I already have an implementation running which utilizes this TensorFlow Hub module: https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1 and performs fine-tuning utilizing the included pre-trained weights.

I now would like to use [the same TensorFlow Hub module](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1) but discard the provided weights and use my own kernel initializer (e.g. tf.initializers.truncated_normal, tf.initializers.he_normal, etc...).

How can I modify the trainable variables in the TFHub module to use a custom initializer? Just to be clear, I want to replace the pre-trained weights at runtime, and just keep the model architecture. Please let me know if I really should be using TFSlim, or the model zoo.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

tfhub_module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1'
initializer = tf.truncated_normal

def main(_):
    _graph = tf.Graph()
    with _graph.as_default():
        module_spec = hub.load_module_spec(tfhub_module_url)
        height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module_spec)
        resized_input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, 3], name='resized_input_tensor')
        m = hub.Module(module_spec, trainable=True)
        bottleneck_tensor = m(resized_input_tensor)
        trainable_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
        # TODO: This fails, because this probably isn't how this is supposed to be done:
        for trainable_var in trainable_vars:
            trainable_var.initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal

    with tf.Session(graph=_graph) as sess:
        print(trainable_vars)


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
tf.app.run()
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do what you want to do, because TF Hub modules are really built to represent pre-trained model pieces. If you only want the graph, you could use tensorflow_models/slim code directly. (Or you could patch the tensorflow_hub library code to not rewire variable initializers with restore ops in the first place.)

EDIT 2019-04-15: See also [tensorflow_hub issue #267](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/267): In TF2, the notion of initializers is going away, so the TF Hub Authors don't want to start depending on it for the TF1 API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have still been pursuing this; and I think you are right. I have made some progress and will update the question with my findings in case anyone else is looking for a partial solution. I am currently working on patching the library code to bypass the checkpoint initializer assignment ops that are present by default in the computational graph.  It has not been straightforward, nor easy!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the issue you linked to is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I've since switched to Keras for this exact reason, I would advise others to do the same.